# How can I generate the status values(count) in Dashboard

Tags: google-app-maker

How can I generate the status values(count) in Dashboard (refer the image)

My status option is " WIP, "Open", Closed" and "Total", 
[image]

I have tried generating the values using @datasources.Requset.query.filters.Status._equals but not succeed

Comment: You can find some inspiration in https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/qa-forum/ and https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/ apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to create a [Calculated Model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/calculated) first, in which you need to write your logic to count each status value, then you can display these values directly in this graph.

Here's my code to generate a pie chart on similar approach.

```javascript
// server script
var calculatedModelRecords = [];
var recordsByStatus = {};
var allRecord = app.models.DataSource.newQuery().run();

var pendingrecord = app.models.NewCalculatedDatasource.newRecord();
pendingrecord.count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < allRecord.length; i++) {
     var record = allRecord[i];

     if(record.Status == 'Pending') {
       // follow same approach for rest of the status count
       pendingrecord.count++;
     }
}

calculatedModelRecords.push(record);

return calculatedModelRecords;
```

Comment: Thanks, i am using G SQL do i need to change my Database

Comment: No, you only need to create a new model in your existing database.

Comment: Can you please tell "what" should be the model type for this kind of calculated model. 1) Calculated SQL 2) Calculated OR 3) Client Side Calculated.